# Find min value and one index above it

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I want to isolate the row in my dataframe that contains the minimum value under column Price, but also want to isolate the row just above that.
Here is my code to isolate the row containing the minimum price in the dataframe:

```
pZ = df[df.Price == df.Price.min()]
```

How do I isolate the row with an index 1 less than pZ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_loc` to get the row number from index and `idxmin()` to get the index of the minimal element:

```
pZ = df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(df['Price'].idxmin())-1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer—this looks like its correct but I think the parentheses are a little messed up. I am very new to python and am not sure what the proper correction would be. Can you help? Thanks again.

Comment: @ThomasMurray I've checked it and it works correctly

Comment: Ah I must've used before you edited the answer, thanks. Is there any way to make an output preserving the dataframe format? As of now, I get an answer where the  column titles have become the index and the index has become a column title.

Comment: It is a Series, just add `to_frame()` at the end.

Comment: Or maybe you need to transpose it with `.T`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `shift`:

```
mask = df['Price'].eq(df['Price'].min())
df[mask|mask.shift(-1)]
```

dummy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Price': [3,2,1,0,4,5]})
mask = df['Price'].eq(df['Price'].min())
df[mask|mask.shift(-1)]
```

output:

```
   Price
2      1
3      0
```

Comment: I used this and got the following error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'float' and 'bool'

Comment: What is the | symbol used for? Does it have an equivalent that I could use instead?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data (edit the question)? `|` is the logical `or` for pandas. Here this means, the matching column or the previous one.

Comment: @ThomasMurray if you want only the previous row use `df[mask.shift(-1)]` The advantage of this solution is that you can match several min if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Series.shift() to access values around others.

```py
is_min_val = df.Price == df.Price.min()
is_above_min_val = df.Price.shift(1) == df.Price.min()
pZ = df[is_min_val | is_above_min_val]
```

Or because the equality of two Series is itself a Series

```py
is_min_val = df.Price == df.Price.min()
pZ = df[is_min_val | is_min_val.shift(1)]
```